# How to solve "Acces is denied" when sending mail using New-MgUserMessage?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I try to write PowerShell script to send email using Microsoft Graph.

I've registered the application and I can connect to Graph using this script :

```
$TenantId = "xxxx"
$ClientId = "xxx"
$CertificateThumbprint  = "xxx"

Connect-MgGraph  -TenantId  $TenantId  -ClientId $ClientId -CertificateThumbprint  $CertificateThumbprint
```

But when i try tro send an email

```
$NewMessage = New-MgUserMessage -UserId $MsgFrom -Body $MessageBody -ToRecipients $EmailRecipient -Subject $MsgSubject
```

I got the error

```
New-MgUserMessage : Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

My application has "Mail.Send" permission and "Grant Admin Consent".

So, I understand I have a permission problem but i dont know how manage that.

How can I set permissions ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question if it can help: to use New-MgUserMessage it is necessary to have the rights Mail.Send and Mail.ReadWrite.